# Is there are way to make iOS password field to allow pasting text when using KONY for development?

Tags: ios, temenos-quantum

We believe that the use of strong passwords in combination with password manager will improve security.

Using the KONY mobile framework we noticed that it is not possible to copy paste text into a password field (secureTextEntry=true) on iOS. It works on Android.

Is there are way to make iOS password field to allow pasting text when using KONY for development?